# Calculating the total amount in the cart?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, google-cloud-firestore

I couldn't get the total price in the list of items in the RecylerView . I got the price from the firestore and multiplied with the quantity but how to get the total price of the added items in the recylerView. My problem is that the total cost of the items is not calculated.
Thanks!
my code:

```
 public class ItemCartRecyelerAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter<ItemCartRecyelerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private static final String TAG = "ItemRecyelerAdapter";



public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void OnItemSelected(DocumentSnapshot item);

}

private OnItemSelectedListener mListener;


public ItemCartRecyelerAdapter(Query query, OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
    super(query);
    mListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cart_adapter,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
}

public void deleteItem(int position){
    getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}


static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView item_name, item_company, item_price, discount_price, discount;
    ImageView item_image, subtract_image;
    ElegantNumberButton quantityPicker;

    private int TotalPrice = 0;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView);
        item_company = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_company);
        item_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        item_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        quantityPicker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityPicker);
        subtract_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtract_image);
        discount_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_discount_price);
        discount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.discount);

    }

    public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot, final OnItemSelectedListener listener) {

        final Attachment attachment = snapshot.toObject(Attachment.class);
        Resources resources = itemView.getResources();


        item_name.setText(attachment.getItem_name());
        item_company.setText(attachment.getItem_brand());
        discount.setText(String.valueOf(attachment.getItem_discount()) + "%\noff");
        quantityPicker.setNumber(String.valueOf(attachment.getItem_quantity()));


        if (attachment.getItem_discount() != null && attachment.getItem_discount() != 0) {
            subtract_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            discount_price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            discount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Integer discountedPrice = attachment.getItem_price() * attachment.getItem_discount() / 100;
            Integer priceDiscounted = attachment.getItem_price() - discountedPrice;
            discount_price.setText(String.valueOf(priceDiscounted));
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "bind: Urs: " + attachment.getUrls());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> result : attachment.getUrls().entrySet()) {
            String key = result.getKey();
            String value = result.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "bind: Urls+valuew" + key + value);

            //Load Image
            Glide.with(item_image.getContext())
                    .load(value)
                    .into(item_image);
        }


        quantityPicker.setRange(0, 10);

        quantityPicker.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onValueChange: postion " + attachment.getItem_id());
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("oldValue: %d   newValue: %d", oldValue, newValue));

                passData(newValue, attachment.getItem_id(), oldValue);

            }


            private void passData(int newValue, String item_id, int oldValue) {
                // Go to the details page for the selected restaurant

                //sharing to seperate cart node in store

                if (newValue == 0) {
                    FirebaseFirestore updateQ = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    DocumentReference CartREf = updateQ.collection("Cart")
                            .document(item_id);
                    CartREf.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Succed to quantity");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failed to change cart");
                        }
                    });

                    FirebaseFirestore dQ = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    DocumentReference QuanityRef = dQ.collection("fruits & vegetables")
                            .document("UyGXpk2n1A6mHsUcYjCi")
                            .collection("Organic Fruits")
                            .document(item_id);
                    QuanityRef.update("item_quantity", newValue).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Success updated item_quanity in Products");
                        }
                    });
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "passData: new update StrARTED");
                FirebaseFirestore updateQ = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                DocumentReference CartREf = updateQ.collection("Cart")
                        .document(item_id);
                CartREf.update("item_quantity", newValue).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Succed to quantity");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failed to change cart");
                    }
                });

                Log.d(TAG, "passData: new update StrARTED");
                FirebaseFirestore dQ = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                DocumentReference QuanityRef = dQ.collection("fruits & vegetables")
                        .document("UyGXpk2n1A6mHsUcYjCi")
                        .collection("Organic Fruits")
                        .document(item_id);
                QuanityRef.update("item_quantity", newValue).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Succed to quantity");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failed to change cart");
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        int items_price = attachment.getItem_price() * attachment.getItem_quantity();
        item_price.setText("INR " + items_price + "Rs");

        TotalPrice += TotalPrice + items_price;
        Log.d(TAG, "bind: Toatal = " + TotalPrice);

        //Click Listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.OnItemSelected(snapshot);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

i tried in this way but i could only get the single item result .

```
    int items_price = attachment.getItem_price() * attachment.getItem_quantity();
    item_price.setText("INR " + items_price + "Rs");

    TotalPrice += TotalPrice + items_price;
    Log.d(TAG, "bind: Toatal = " + TotalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int items_total_price =0;


  public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot, final OnItemSelectedListener 
     listener) {

    final Attachment attachment = snapshot.toObject(Attachment.class);
    items_total_price+=attachment.getItem_price()

    //////////// } //when the recycle view comes to the last item you will have the total items' price
```

Comment: I tried the way you said but couldn't get the total . only single items total is getting viewed

Comment: @Shivas Which item's price you are seeing? the last one?

Comment: @ArunYogeshwaran yes if using only last item is getting shown

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in

> onBindViewHolder

```
private int total_price = 0;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Attachment attachment = getSnapshot(position).toObject(Attachment.class);
    total_price += attachment.getItem_price()
}
```

Comment: This is wrong...the price will increase unendingly as you scroll, because things will get rebound (the other one is wrong for the same reason).

Comment: @Shivas The problem with your implementation is that you are sending the firebase Query object directly to the Recyclerview and querying firebase inside RV. That's not correct. From the view(Activity or Fragment), get the list of objects using firebase query and the pass it to RecyclerView. Then you can easily calculate the total price

Comment: @RyanM yes the price didn't work as expected . what can be done?

Comment: @ArunYogeshwaran okay i did use this because of the firestoreAdapter which was much simplified. so i went for this !

Answer (score 0):

> This is to query only the items in stock and exclude the items out of stock

```
private void totalSum() {

    Query cartQuery = cartRef.orderByChild("in_stock").startAfter(0);

    cartQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            int sum = 0;
            int savings = 0;
            int totalCount = 0;

            if(snapshot.getValue() == null) {
                finish();
            }

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Cart cart = dataSnapshot.getValue(Cart.class);
                assert cart != null;

                int price = cart.getFinal_price() * cart.getCount();
                int actualPrice = cart.getActual_price() * cart.getCount();

                int totalSavings = actualPrice - price;
                savings =+ savings + totalSavings;

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: savings: " + ("₹" + savings + "savings" ));

                if(savings != 0) {
                    cartSavings.setText("₹" + savings + " savings");
                    cartSavings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    cartSavings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                int count = cart.getCount();

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: count" + count);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Price:" + price);

                sum =+ sum + price;
                totalCount =+ totalCount + count;

                itemTotalCountTv.setText(getString(R.string.rupee) + sum);
                packagingCountTv.setText(getString(R.string.rupee) + 4);

                subTotalCountTv.setText(getString(R.string.rupee) + (sum + 4));

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Sum: " + sum);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Items: " + totalCount);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```